# what is the best practice to create a .jar file from a java project?

Tags: java, jar

what is the best practice to create a .jar file from a java project??

Comment: Do you mean the best way to create a jar, or when/why you should create a jar?

Comment: Creating a .jar file is just packing your classes and whatever resource files it might need into a single archive. What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse IDE is the best way for new comers. Just select the project right click export File, select jar anf filename.

Comment: If your not already familiar enough with Eclipse to create a jar, it is a rather daunting interface, as noted in the "Worst UI" thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238177/worst-ui-youve-ever-used/568142#568142

Comment: Using the GUI is about the worst practice for making a .jar file.  It's not scripted to be repeatable by others AND you have little control over the contents.

Answer (score 11):

Some points to consider:

- Create proper MANIFEST.MF, which should contain:

  - Build date;
  - Author;
  - Implementation-version;
- Use a script/program - like an [Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/) - which takes care of properly creating a manifest file.

---

Here's a simple ant file which builds a java project, adapted from the [Ant tutorial](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html):

```
<project>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes"/>
</target>

<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" basedir="build/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run">
    <java jar="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>

</project>
```

Comment: I think newcomers should learn to use the real tools -- namely those provided by the JDK -- before using third party software like Ant. It's like using an IDE when learning a new language.

Comment: Perhaps. But I see no mention of 'newcomers', just 'best practices'.

Comment: It's quite obvious the person asking the question is probably not an expert.

Comment: I answered the question. And for an 'expert' I would've pointed to maven.apache.org, BTW.

Comment: I agree. @fenec asked for best practice.  Scripting the build is repeatable and easily passed to others.  Would recommend Maven to an expert but it's still a bit raw to be considered "best practice" for everyone.

Comment: If Sun would just publish their ^%#^ jars in a public repository...  Then Maven could be the best practice out of the box.

Answer (score 7):

Read up on the basics of Sun's JAR format at [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/). In my opinion you should learn the basics -- namely MANIFESTs, the SDK tools -- before jumping into third party tools such as the following.

The Jar command line tool distributed with the Sun JDK:

```
jar -cf myjar.jar base_src_folder
```

Where `base_src_folder` is the parent directory holding your source code.

Alternatively you could use a build tool such as [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org). It has features such as the [JAR task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) to do this for you.

Answer (score 5):

[Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), for projects which are dependent on other projects.

Admittedly, Maven may be overkill for learning projects, but it is invaluable for larger, distributed ones.

Comment: If Maven were properly integrated into Eclipse (like ant is) then it would not only be the best practice, it would also be the easiest. Maven builds like ant, if the scripts were pre-written for you.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Ant

Answer (score 0):

Ant is not quite easy to begin with. Instead, I would suggest using an IDE, for instance [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/), which creates an Ant script under the hood. All you have to do is to hit "build", and you get a .jar file as result.

Comment: I don't agree that its not easy to start using Ant, but it really comes handy with Netbeans. +1

Comment: +1 on atc's comment. it didn't hard for me to learn Ant. I felt quite easy.

Comment: Well, anybody can copy tutorial scripts to get started, but at least I find it tricky to really understand and customize them. Hitting F11 is easier, but maybe it's just me :-)